# Save a Child for a existent Parent

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, inheritance, hql

I have a model with some inherits and it is using nhibernate to persisti on a Database. The nhibernate mapping with fluent nhibernate is working fine, but I have a scenario where I need to save a child for a existent parent. My model looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   // other properties
}

public class ItemCommercial : Item
{
   public decimal Value { get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

In my Database, the respective tables are related by `Id <-> Id` (one per one).

I would like to know, how to Save just a `ItemCommercial` instance for a existent `Item` on database. I have the Id of the Item, but I do not know howt to say to nhibernate  to say just the Child, instead creating a new Item, for sample:

```
session.Save(itemCommercialObj); // will create a Item and ItemCommercial with the same Id
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you coud manualy write function in `ItemCommercial` witch will return `Item` object with data you want. So if you call `Item i = itemCommercialObj.ConvertMyselfToItem()` you will get wanted object

Comment: No, I can't, I have to use my ORM because it will be used by other differents database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I also [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387672/nhibernate-table-per-type-persist-child-from-existing-parent)

No, it is not possible to "upgrade" an already persisted object to its subclass. Nhibernate simply doesn't support this. 
If you safe the subclass with the same ID as the base class, Nhibernate simply creates a copy with a new ID of the object instead of creating the reference to Member...

So basically you could do either

1. Copy the data of Customer into Member, delete customer and save Member
2. Use a different object structure without subclasses where Member is a different table with it's own ID and a reference to Customer
3. Use native sql to insert the row into Member...

Answer (score 0):

you can not the runtimetype of an object like that hence NH does not support it. Change the design to

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CommercialValue CommercialValue { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class CommercialValue
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

and a one-to-one mapping. Then it is as simple as setting the CommercialValue property