# NHibernate table per type persist child from existing parent

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, persistence, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 classes, `Member.cs` and `Customer.cs` and using table-per-type inheritance mapping described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726679/save-a-child-for-a-existent-parent?rq=1) poses the same problem, but with no answer.

**Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer
{
}
```

**Member.cs**

```
public class Member : Customer
{
    public Member(Customer customer)
    {
        CreateFromCustomer(customer);
    }

    private void CreateFromCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        // Here I assume I'll assign the Id so NHibernate wouldn't have to create a new Customer and know what Customer to be referred
        Id = customer.Id;
    }
}
```

**CustomerMap.cs**

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
    }
}
```

**MemberMap.cs**

```
public class MemberMap : SubclassMap<Member>
{
    public MemberMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("Id");
    }
}
```

I tried several test case :

**Test1.cs**

```
[Test]
public void CanAddCustomer()
{
    var customerRepo = /* blablabla */;

    using (var tx = NHibernateSessionManager.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
    {
        var customer = new Customer()

        customerRepo.RegisterCustomer(customer);

        tx.Commit();
    }

    using (var tx = NHibernateSessionManager.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
    {
        /* Get the persisted customer */
        var customer = customerRepo.GetCustomerByWhatever();

        var member = customerRepo.RegisterMember(new Member(customer));

        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to have :

1 customer and 1 member which is a child of that customer

Instead I have :

2 customers (1 that is what was correctly created and 1 with all null columns) and 1 member that Id referred to all null columns Customer.

Is it the expected behavior?

I understand if we were wanted to create a child object from a transient parent object, this is a correct behavior.

But what if we were to create a child object that refers to an existing parent object?

The link I provided doesn't cover any persistence example, neither does googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

No, it is not possible to "upgrade" an already persisted object to its subclass. Nhibernate simply doesn't support this. That's why you see 2 customers and one member entry. This is actually the expected behavior because Nhibernate simply creates a copy with a new ID of the object instead of creating the reference to Member...

So basically you could do either

1. Copy the data of Customer into Member, delete customer and save Member
2. Use a different object structure without subclasses where Member is a different table with it's own ID and a reference to Customer
3. Use native sql to insert the row into Member...

### Some example:

Your classes could look like this

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Member : Customer
{
    public virtual string MemberSpecificProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, Member could have additional properties, but will have the same properties as Customer of cause, too.

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

and for the sub class, you have to map **additional** properties only!

```
public class MemberMap : SubclassMap<Member>
{
    public MemberMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.MemberSpecificProperty);
    }
}
```

testing it

```
{
    session.Save(new Customer()
    {
        Name ="Customer A"
    });

    session.Save(new Member()
    {
        Name = "Customer B",
        MemberSpecificProperty = "something else"
    });

    session.Flush();
}
```

This will create 2 entries in the customer table and one row into Member table. So this is as expected, because we created one customer and one member...

Now the "upgrade" from Customer A to Member:

```
using (var session = NHibernateSessionFactory.Current.OpenSession())
{
    session.Save(new Customer()
    {
        Name ="Customer A"
    });

    session.Flush();
}

using (var session = NHibernateSessionFactory.Current.OpenSession())
{
    var customer = session.Query<Customer>().FirstOrDefault();
    //var member = customer as Member;
    var member = new Member()
    {
        Name = customer.Name,
        MemberSpecificProperty = "something else"
    };
    session.Delete(customer);
    session.Save(member);

    session.Flush();
}
```

Comment: I did tried this method earlier, but I have some concerns : About Id reference, since Member is derived from Customer, they have the same Id generation strategy, says Generated.Guid. What happens when I assigned Member.Id from an existing Customer.Id? Does the Id gets persisted, or a new Id gets generated? I'm concerning about what if Customer need to have a IList<Something> here.

And it also troublesome to really delete an Customer, because basically I liked Cascade.All strategy to persisting new entity. But I do willing to change to Cascade.SaveUpdate if necessary.

Comment: As I wrote, you cannot reuse the already stored customer with ID A to create a Member with ID A, nHibernate will generate a new ID B and store the customer+member row within the database with ID B.

Comment: So how to resolve when the there are some other data that references the existing customer? Should them too be recreated? Doing recreation for the whole object graph would be a lot of work..

Comment: @SamuelAdam yes, as I wrote, recreate, use a different object strategy or use native sql. I'd sugget using a different strategy if this is a common scenario in your application. Meaning NOT having the Member inherit from Customer... simply have a one-to-one relationship will work, of cause this would mean that every customer would might have to have a member